# Laravel upload image through Cloudder and Cloudinary in update method with getRealPath() error "Call to a member function getRealPath() on null"

Tags: laravel

issue is i also use cloudder in create Products, done. However in edit, error is "Call to a member function getRealPath() on null"

Here is controller update() method

```
Cloudder::upload($request->file('images')->getRealPath(), $current_time);
    $product->images = Cloudder::getResult()['url'];
    $product->sale = $request->input('sale');
    $product->description = $request->input('description');
    $product->detail = $request->input('detail');
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/admin/product');
```

Here is views, input file upload image

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left" for="inputSuccess">Upload image</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row ml-1">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <input type="file" name="images" class="mr-2" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this);">
                                    <span class="badge badge-green">Choose new image...</span>
                                    <img id="upload-image" src="#" alt="new image here" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <span class="badge badge-green">Previous Image</span>
                                    <img src="{{ $product->images }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"/>
                                </div>
                                @if($errors->has('images'))
                                <label class="text-danger">*{{$errors->first('images')}}</label>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getPathname` it is the method of `SplFileInfo` which is extended by laravel `UploadedFile` class

```
Cloudder::upload($request->file('images')->getPathname(), $current_time);
```